# How do you reverse sort and hide the count from the SXA dropdown fiilter?

Tags: sxa, search-facet

Can the following two be answered without requiring code changes?

1. How to hide/remove the inside dropdown count number?
2. How to sort the year lastest on top?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the items in the Content tree, depending on the tree sorting it will fetch the items, unless you have set the sorting on the query. You can remove the number with the CSS,

If I recall correct, the numbers are in the span along with the values.